# Define a bijection between the set of positive integers and the set of all pairs of positive integers

Tags: cardinals, infinity

How do I do this? I know that by finding a bijection, we will prove that the sets are of the "same size."
What function can I show to match the set of positive integers(Z+), to the set of, the set of pairs (Z+ * Z+) of positive integers?

Comment: Have you had any thoughts of your own about this?

Comment: Hint: Draw a 2-d grid to represent the positive integers. One way of solving this is to trace a path starting from the origin that will hit all positive pairs of numbers, without ever going back to the same pair twice.

Comment: In this instance, in fact, you can use the massive overkill that is Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein to *produce* a bijection from the injections $f: x \mapsto (x, 1)$ and $g: (p, q) \mapsto 2^{p-1} 3^{q-1}$. This is possible using the proof from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem because the map $gf: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is increasing, so you can only walk back a bounded distance along the chains.

Comment: One possibility is to take a pair to the number with the digits of both interleaved, possibly adding leading zeros to one.  For example, $(28, 3356) \mapsto 3032586$.  And for the inverse, take the digits at odd vs. even place values.